# XCode : interface builder : Storyboards and View

Tags: xcode, uiview, interface-builder

In storyboard, I can't add View Objects (like View or TableView) but just (Table)View Controller Objects? I could think that it's because my storyboard just wants controller.. But I can add Buttons,labels, and other objects that hasn't "controller".. why this behavior?

Comment: are you really sure that you can simply drag a button into storyboard which has no view controller?

Comment: no, but I can't drag a tableview inside a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Documentation:

> Using storyboards, you can design the view controllers that compose your application as scenes in the Xcode design canvas and visually define the navigation between the scenes using segues.

You cannot use any element other than view controller in storyboard. Either you go for xib to drop in all the elements you need or go for storyboard and use by view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first add view controller and add those "View Object" on top of it. Story is based on the collections of view controllers. If you want to design the single "View Object" You have to use NIB files.

You may reference this [tutorial](http://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-user-interfaces-storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-custom-code).